# fastify.setValidatorCompiler is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I have fastify `2.14` installed. I am following the documentation to use custom validation library.

Here's my code:

```js
import fastify from 'fastify';

const app = fastify({});

app.setValidatorCompiler(({schema}) => data => schema.validate(data)); // setValidatorCompiler is not a function

console.log(app.setValidatorCompiler) // undefined 

export default app;
```

I also tried passing it in the route options and typescript doesn't recognize it as a field.

also `setSerializerCompiler` is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like they have wrong documentation versioning.

I was reading version `2.14` documentation and it was for `3-alpha`.

Installing the `3-alpha` version solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
fastify.setValidatorCompiler(({ schema, method, url, httpPart }) => {
  return ajv.compile(schema)
})
```

https://www.fastify.io/docs/v3.3.x/Validation-and-Serialization/#validator-compiler